# MVC DropDownList Select Populates ListBox (Both Selects)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, listbox

I have an MVC view that has a model with a `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` which populates a `@Html.DropDownList` (Form select).
I want to write code so that when a item in the drop down list is selected, it will populate another listbox (also a form select) with values from the server.

Should I use AJAX to get a seperate partial view that contains the listbox with the values on each click of the dropdownlist?  Or should I generate a listbox on load and then use WebAPI to just get the data on each click?

It seems like a simple problem but I'm trying to figure out my models and views and the best approach.

Comment: I would go with your first suggestion

Comment: @MattBodily any specific reason, one way or the other?  I appreciate the comments.

Comment: a partial view is going to be your easiest way of setting it up.  You can also manually load the data into the list box every time.  googling dependend drop downs will give you several examples of that method.  it is more work to set up though

Comment: For this type of cascading cases go with ajax-calls on change of parent element and I'd suggest always keep maintain light-weight in response. So go with Json Result as response (in front-end with JavaScript/jQuery construct options and set them to DropDownList) rather PartialView Result upon the onchange of first list option item

Comment: @VenkataPanga so you are also suggesting to create an empty list box and then populate it with an AJAX call?

Comment: Yes Keeping Empty List box is good and required to persist the state also it is important to manage other event-actions & custom data attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Populate your dropdownlist
2. Create an empty list box.
3. Have a javascript function that fires on dropdown list change event and do ajax call to the action method that returns the json result.
4. Bind the json data to the list box on success.

Comment: That is really what it boils down to. Do I use an empty list box with Json data AJAX calls or do I use a Partial View HTML returns with AJAX? I know JSON is better for the size of data but is creating an empty list considered good design?

Comment: @Isa Fram If you use a partial view to create a list box then you are creating the control every time when the dropdown is changed where as loading the list box is much more simple than that. If you feel that the empty list box is annoying why don't you make it disabled on page load and enable it when the dropdown value gets changed which will tells the user that the list box is a cascade one.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather go with an Ajax since other dropdown lists are dependent on your first dropdown.

and in your controller, just have a JsonResult, something like this:

```
public JSonResult getDropdownItems(your parameters)
{
    //do some iteration in your context

    return Json( /*list or iEnumerable*/, Json.AllowGet);
}
```